# Problem in scraping 'td' values from website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the website to save all the info on all the pages according to the years. I'm not getting any error but not getting the details as well. It has to have the rows given in 1, 2.
[HTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR3P8.png)

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong. This is the code :

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

file = "Details2.csv"
Headers = ("ID", "ID", "# of Exploits", "Type(s)", "Publish Date", "Update Date", "Score", "Gained Access Level", "Access", "Complexity", "Authentication", "Confiden", "Integr", "Avail")
f = open(file, "w")
csvriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
csvriter.writerow(Headers)
for page in range(1,130):
  try:  
    url = "https://www.justfly.com/vulner-list.php?vendor_id=0& product_id=0&version_id=0&page={}&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=2015&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=6484&sha=f941b721732be362e81064704448767014116e7c".format(page)
#html = urlopen(url)
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()

bs=BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
table_body=bs.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all("div", {"class":"srrowns"})
for row in rows:
  cols=row.find_all('td')
  cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
  print("cols", file = f)
  f.write("{}".format(cols).replace(",",",",",",",",",","|")+ "\n")
  except: AttributeError  
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script. It should fetch the required data you have mentioned above. Turn out that you picked the wrong tag name `div`. That should be `tr` instead.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=0& product_id=0&version_id=0&page={}&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=2015&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=6484&sha=f941b721732be362e81064704448767014116e7c"

Headers = ("CVE ID", "CWE ID", "# of Exploits", "Vulnerability Type(s)", "Publish Date", "Update Date", "Score", "Gained Access Level", "Access", "Complexity", "Authentication", "Confidentiality", "Integrity", "Availability")
with open("Details2.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    csvriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvriter.writerow(Headers)

    for page in range(1,5): #change here the highest number you wanna go across
        res = requests.get(url.format(page), headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
        bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        for row in bs.find(id='vulnslisttable').find_all("tr", class_="srrowns"):
            cols = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in row.find_all('td')]
            print(cols)
            csvriter.writerow(cols)
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you.